Single components inputs re-render all time on change one input value
The issue I'm facing is related to how React handles state updates and re-renders. When you change the value of one field in your form (name, email, or phone), all three input components re-render because they all depend on the same formData state. React re-renders the entire component when the state changes, which is why all inputs re-render, even if only one field's value has changed.
In below, if you change value of name all 3 input components will be re-render.
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ name: '', email: '', phone: '';

<FormInput
                    label="Name"
                    placeholder="Enter name"
                    id="name"
                    value={formData.name}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />

                <FormInput
                    label="Email"
                    placeholder="Enter email"
                    type='email'
                    id="email"
                    value={formData.email}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />

                <FormInput
                    label="Phone"
                    placeholder="Enter phone"
                    type='number'
                    id="phone"
                    value={formData.phone}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />

FormInput.jsx
import { forwardRef} from "react";
import { cx } from "../../utils/helper";

export const commonInputCss = "w-full border border-neutral-300 rounded-xl p-4 outline-none text-text-700 placeholder:text-text-disabled bg-white disabled:bg-text-disabled disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50 disabled:placeholder:text-main-black";

const FormInput = forwardRef(({
    label, type = "text", id, inputCss, ...props
}, ref) => {

    return (
        <div className={cx("relative flex flex-col gap-y-1")}>
            {label && (
                <label htmlFor={id} className={cx(
                    "text-text-700 text-sm text-medium",
                    labelCss
                )}>
                    {label}
                </label>
            )}

            <input
                type={type}
                name={id}
                id={id}
                ref={ref}
                {...props}
                className={cx(
                    commonInputCss,
                    inputCss,
                )}
            />
        </div>
    );
});

export default FormInput;

But, do we need to re-render all to change one property value?


We can use different state for all input, which will be more line of code. (not preferable)
We can use useRef hook for all input, which also be more line of code. (not preferable)
You can use memo hook to memorize inputs value.
You can use react-hook-from package. Which, follow like useRef hook but no need to write multiple lines of code. etc.

Example using React Hook Form Package
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import FormInput from '../../shared/forms/FormInput';
import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const AddSellerModal = ({ isOpen, closeModal }) => {

    const { control, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm({ 
        defaultValues: { name: '', email: '', email: '', phone: '' } 
    });

    return (
        <>
                <div className='my-10 space-y-5'>
                    <Controller
                        name="name"
                        control={control}
                        render={({ field }) => (
                            <FormInput
                                label="Shop Name"
                                placeholder="Enter shop name"
                                id="name"
                                {...field}
                            />
                        )}
                    />

                    <Controller
                        name="location"
                        control={control}
                        render={({ field }) => (
                            <FormInput
                                label="Location"
                                placeholder="Enter location"
                                id="location"
                                {...field}
                            />
                        )}
                    />

                    <Controller
                        name="email"
                        control={control}
                        render={({ field }) => (
                            <FormInput
                                label="Email"
                                placeholder="Enter email"
                                id="email"
                                type='email'
                                {...field}
                            />
                        )}
                    />

                    <Controller
                        name="phone"
                        control={control}
                        render={({ field }) => (
                            <FormInput
                                label="Phone"
                                placeholder="Enter phone"
                                id="phone"
                                type='number'
                                {...field}
                            />
                        )}
                    />
                </div>
            </CustomContainerModal>
        </>

    );
};

export default AddSellerModal;

